# Visual Studio 2015 CE crashes while debugging this code

Tags: crash, visual-studio-debugging

Stepping over the following code makes Visual Studio to fill up the RAM and then it crashes. Did I just made a terrible mistake, or this is a Visual Studio bug?

```
namespace d
{
    class base
    {};

    template <typename Base>
    class dummy : public Base
    {
    public:
        dummy()
        {}
    };
}

class base : public d::base
{
public:
    base()
    {}
};

int main()
{
    //d::dummy<base> dd;
    using dummy_t = d::dummy<base>;
    dummy_t dd2;

    return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment the first line inside main the problem doesn't seem to appear. If I uncomment the first line and comment the following two then again, the problem doesn't appear. Also if I change the "base" class (which is derived from d::base) to something else the problem goes away.